# question about relative clause

Tags: relative-clauses

> Still, *the filial (and often proprietary) attachment **that Orwell’s work tends to evoke in his admirers** points to something else*: the morally urgent yet highly companionable nature of his writing, which can leave one with the feeling of having been directly addressed by a mind worthy of emulation.

The subject of the sentence is **the filial attachment** and the main verb is **points**.
"that Orwell's work tends to evoke in his admirers" is a relative clause(modifying attachment),
and the missing noun behind **evoke** is **that** , and **that** represents **filial attachment**.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes. You have it exactly. (comment because it's too short for an answer)

Comment: @ColinFine Thank you so much, can I say the relative clause originally is "Orwell's work tends to evoke the filial attachment in his admirers."?

Comment: Yes, except that it wouldn't have _the_. It's only because it is further specified (in this case by a relative clause) that _the_ is required or allowed.